# JTable cell text space not shown when print out

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable

method to print the table.

```
public static void PrintTable(JTable table,String title) {
        try {
            MessageFormat headerFormat = new MessageFormat(title);
            MessageFormat footerFormat = new MessageFormat("{0}");
            boolean complete = table.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH,headerFormat, footerFormat);
            if (complete) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Printing Completed.");
            }else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Printing Canceled !");
            }
            } catch (PrinterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        }
    }
```

The application output table column seems like this (Correct).

```
| Address                     |
  :--------------------------
| Kathmandu Nepal
| Kirtipur 5 Kathmandu Nepal  |
| Baneswor 10 Kathmandu Nepal |
| Balkhu 2 Kathmandu Nepal    |
```

But a hard copy of print is like this:(Missing space between some words).

```
| Address                  |
 :------------------------
| Kathmandu Nepal
| Kirtipur5KathmanduNepal  |
| Baneswor10KathmanduNepal |
| Balkhu2KathmanduNepal    |
```

How to overcome this problem? I googled but did not found the related solution.

Comment: Maybe show case on how your JTable is created, size, etc?
Interesting that JTable.PrintMode.NORMAL did not help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened due to the 'Microsoft Sans Serif' font for JTable. I changed the font to 'Tahoma'. It works.